# Keyboard not popping up when testing plaid_flutter with iOS simulator

Tags: flutter, dart, plaid

The keyboard is not showing when I try to enter the User login details in Plaid interface in the iOS simulator.

Can anyone give me a solution to this problem?

Here is the exact code I used:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:plaid_flutter/plaid_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  PlaidLink _plaidLinkToken;
  var newpublicToken;
  var CLIENT_ID = "NTER YOUR PLAID CLIENT ID";
  var SECRET = "ENTER YOUR PLAID SECRET";
  var unique_per_user = "user_good";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLinkToken();
  }

  getLinkToken() async {
    var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    };

var data =
    '{ "client_id": "$CLIENT_ID", "secret": "$SECRET", "user": { "client_user_id": "$unique_per_user" }, "client_name": "Plaid App", "products": ["auth"], "country_codes": ["US"], "language": "en", "webhook": "https://sample-web-hook.com", "account_filters": { "depository": { "account_subtypes": ["checking"] } } }';

    var res = await http.post('https://sandbox.plaid.com/link/token/create',
        headers: headers, body: data);
    if (res.statusCode != 200)
      throw Exception('http.post error: statusCode= ${res.statusCode}');
    print(res.body);

    Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(res.body);
    var response_link_token = responseJson['link_token'];
    print(response_link_token);

    LinkConfiguration linkTokenConfiguration = LinkConfiguration(
      linkToken: "$response_link_token",
    );

    _plaidLinkToken = PlaidLink(
      configuration: linkTokenConfiguration,
      onSuccess: _onSuccessCallback,
      onEvent: _onEventCallback,
      onExit: _onExitCallback,
    );
  }

  void _onSuccessCallback(String publicToken, LinkSuccessMetadata metadata) {
    print("onSuccess: $publicToken, metadata: ${metadata.description()}");
    newpublicToken = publicToken;
  }

  void _onEventCallback(String event, LinkEventMetadata metadata) {
    print("onEvent: $event, metadata: ${metadata.description()}");
  }

  void _onExitCallback(String error, LinkExitMetadata metadata) {
    print("onExit: $error, metadata: ${metadata.description()}");
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.lightBlue,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => _plaidLinkToken.open(),
                child: Text("Open Plaid Link (Link Token)"),
              ),
                ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

include the following in `pubspec.yaml`

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.1
plaid_flutter: ^1.1.6
http: ^0.12.0+2

Comment: This works for a ordinary textfield in flutter but it does not pop out when used with the PlaidLink login! If I disable the 'Connect Hardware Keyboard', the iOS keyboard pops out but it does not let me use the keyboard for typing!

Comment: just press Command + Control + K keys.

Answer (score 0):

just press `Command + Control + K` keys.